# Need help making regex

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_match("/(11|10|12)([*0-9]+)/i", "11*&!@#")
```

Above is the one i tried.

My requirement is total of 6 characters.

```
10****   
102***
1023**
10234*
102345
```

First two characters should be either 10 or 11 or 12 and the rest of the four characters should be like the pattern above.

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 7):

```
1[0-2][0-9*]{4}
```

This should met your requirements:

- `1` at the begining
- then `0` or `1` or `2`
- then a digit or `*`, four times

**EDIT**

To avoid inputs like `102**5` you can do the pattern more complex:

```
1[0-2](([*]{4})|([0-9][*]{3})|([0-9]{2}[*]{2})|([0-9]{3}[*])|([0-9]{4}))
```

Comment: @tpaksu: I've edited my answer and add more complex solution to avoid wrong passes like yours

Comment: ... Why not just remove the *? I don't get it. Can someone give me a real explanation as to why you would use * in square brackets?

Comment: Because that is the requirement from the question?

Comment: Oh. I guess I didn't fully understand the question, I thought OP ONLY wanted a six digit number with 10, 11 or 12 at the start.

Comment: I long would the pattern be if you are dealing with 16 digits .... `102*************5` ??  Your complex pattern would no longer be readable

Comment: Why not split it into 2 ... one to check the requirement .. the other to check the loop hole .....

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

`#(10|11|12)([0-9]{4})#`

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot to add the `*` in your pattern.

Comment: What does the * denote in brackets?

Comment: Yes, we all wonder what that is, but if it doesn't mean random number, it means character `*`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^(?=.{6})1[0-2]\d{0,4}\**$
```

this will match all your examples and not match strings like:

```
1*2*3*
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(?=.{6})1[0-2]\d{0,4}\**$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .{6}                     any character except \n (6 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1                        '1'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-2]                    any character of: '0' to '2'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{0,4}                  digits (0-9) (between 0 and 4 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \**                      '*' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```